# Location Without GPS and without Network(Using satellite)

Tags: android-gps, satellite

Is there any way to achieve users current location using satellite without GPS(Internet) and without SIM Network.

Answer (score 1):

GPS does not require internet, it requires a gps chip and a processing chip.

The GPS is multiple satellites (what you are asking for) that transmit signals to the ground, these satellite orbit the earth in the LEO (low earth orbit) and there are enough of them to cover the whole globe.

We need internet to fetch the map tiles, street names, traffic and navigation utilities, not the user location.

So using the signal we get from these satellites can be processed into the location of the user with accuracy depending on how many satellites you are listening to (minimum of 3).